# How to create recursive hierarchy in webonyx/graphql?

Tags: php, graphql

I want to create hierarchy tree-like structure.

```php
$fieldOptionsType = new ObjectType([
    'name' => 'Options',
    'fields' => [
        'nested' => [
            'type' => Type::listOf($fieldType), // $fieldType not initialized yet.
        ],
    ],
]);

$fieldType = new ObjectType([
    'name' => 'Field',
    'fields' => [
        'options' => [
            'type' => $fieldOptionsType,
        ],
    ],
]);
```

I have problem, that variable `$fieldType` used first isnt created yet. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the below code, this will build a tree structure.

```
private ObjectType $fieldOptionsType;
private ObjectType $fieldType;
private array $objectTypes;

$this->fieldOptionsType = $this->objectTypes['Options'] ??= new ObjectType([
    'name' => 'Options',
    'fields' => [
        'nested' => [
            'type' => fn() => Type::listOf($this->fieldType),
        ],
    ],
]);

$this->fieldType = $this->objectTypes['Field'] ??= new ObjectType([
    'name' => 'Field',
    'fields' => [
        'options' => [
            'type' => fn() => $this->fieldOptionsType,
        ],
    ],
]);
```